# Self-Adjoint Maps must map to real

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

A theorem in my book(LADR) says that $T$ is self-adjoint if and only if  $\langle Tv,v\rangle$ maps any $v$ on the complex space to a real number.

Why is the significance of this relation? What's so special to always mapping to real numbers? Would appreciate some intuitions and insights.

Comment: You say it's  a _theorem_ in the book. Is there a proof included? If so then the proof explains precisely what's so special about this condition...

Comment: Sorry, I did mean self adjoint. The proof is just one or two lines but the author does not expand on it. I would like some more detailed explanation of the relationship between the two

Comment: It would be better if you asked specifically about the parts of the proof you don't understand. I could post a proof, but it would almost surely be almost exactly the same as the proof in the book - that seems pointless.

Comment: @Rahul Deora this statement proves to be useful in later sections. For example, it helps to define positive operators for Complex Vector Spaces. In addition, it further supports the connection the author makes between self-adjoint operators and the reals.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to address our OP Rehul Deora's concerns about the significance of mapping to the real numbers is to present a proof of the proposition referenced in the title and first paragraphs of the question; I hope this is clarifying and otherwise helpful.

The "only if" implication is short and simple: if

$T = T^\dagger, \tag 0$

then

$\forall v \in V, \; \langle Tv, v \rangle = \langle v, T^\dagger v \rangle = \overline{\langle  T^\dagger v, v \rangle}= \overline{\langle Tv, v \rangle} \Longrightarrow \langle Tv, v \rangle \in \Bbb R, \tag{0.5}$

since $\langle Tv, v \rangle$ equals its complex conjugate.

Going the other way appears to be a bit more involved, to wit:

If

$\langle Tv, v \rangle \in \Bbb R, \forall v \in V, \tag1$

then

$\langle v, T^\dagger v \rangle \in \Bbb R, \forall v \in V, \tag2$

and thus

$\langle T^\dagger v, v \rangle  = \overline{\langle v, T^\dagger v \rangle} \in \Bbb R, \forall v \in V, \tag 3$

whence,

$\langle (T - T^\dagger)v, v \rangle = \langle Tv, v \rangle - \langle T^\dagger v, v \rangle \in \Bbb R, \forall v \in V; \tag 4$

but $T - T^\dagger$ is skew-hermitian:

$(T - T^\dagger)^\dagger = T^\dagger - (T^\dagger)^\dagger = T^\dagger - T = -(T - T^\dagger), \tag 5$

and this implies that

$\langle (T - T^\dagger)v, v \rangle = \langle v, (T - T^\dagger)^\dagger v \rangle = \langle v, -(T - T^\dagger) v \rangle$
$= -\langle v, (T - T^\dagger) v \rangle = -\overline{\langle (T - T^\dagger)} v, v \rangle, \tag 6$

that is,

$\langle (T - T^\dagger)v, v \rangle \in i\Bbb R; \tag 7$

(4) and (7) in concert imply

$\langle (T - T^\dagger)v, v \rangle = 0, \tag 8$

$\langle Tv, v \rangle = \langle T^\dagger v, v \rangle, \; \forall v \in V; \tag 9$

now taking

$v = x + y, \tag{10}$

(9) becomes

$\langle T(x + y), x + y \rangle = \langle T^\dagger (x + y), x + y \rangle, \; \forall x, y \in V; \tag{11}$

we expand this out to obtain

$\langle Tx, x \rangle + \langle Tx, y \rangle + \langle Ty, x \rangle + \langle Ty, y \rangle$
$= \langle T^\dagger x, x \rangle + \langle T^\dagger x, y \rangle + \langle T^\dagger y, x \rangle + \langle T^\dagger y, y \rangle, \forall x, y \in V, \tag{12}$

and now again by virtue of (9),

$\langle Tx, y \rangle + \langle Ty, x \rangle = \langle T^\dagger x, y \rangle + \langle T^\dagger y, x \rangle, \forall x, y \in V; \tag{13}$

we substitute $y \to iy$:

$\langle Tx, iy \rangle + \langle T(iy), x \rangle = \langle T^\dagger x, iy \rangle + \langle T^\dagger (iy), x \rangle, \forall x, y \in V, \tag{14}$

that is, by virtue of the usual rules pertaining to hermitian products,

$i\langle Tx, y \rangle - i\langle Ty, x \rangle = i\langle T^\dagger x, y \rangle - i\langle T^\dagger y, x \rangle, \forall x, y \in V, \tag{15}$

we multiply by $i$,

$-\langle Tx, y \rangle + \langle Ty, x \rangle = -\langle T^\dagger x, y \rangle + \langle T^\dagger y, x \rangle, \forall x, y \in V,   \tag{16}$,

subtract (16) from (13):

$2\langle Tx, y \rangle = 
2\langle T^\dagger x, y \rangle, \forall x, y \in V \tag{17}$

and thus at last, again for every $x, y \in V$,

$\langle Tx, y \rangle = 
\langle T^\dagger x, y \rangle \Longrightarrow Tx = T^\dagger x \Longrightarrow T = T^\dagger, \tag{18}$

and we see that $T$ is self-adjoint.

$OE\Delta$.

It is worth noting that there is no restriction of $\dim V$ here; $\dim V = \infty$ is in fact allowed.

Comment: Thanks for this! I have posted a new question with what I was looking for: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3311737/self-adjoint-operators-only-map-to-reals Would appreciate an answer from you

Comment: @RahulDeora:  so vote already!  I'll have a look at your other question.  Cheers!

Comment: Yes let me just digest it

Comment: @RahulDeora:  been looking at your other one,  Cheers!

Comment: Any luck with it? Im wondering if there is an explanation for what i am thinking

Comment: @RahulDeora:  barely had a chance to look at it.  Maybe in an hour or two . . .