# Self-adjoint Operators Only map to Reals

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I want to understand why self-adjoint operators only maps to real numbers in the inner product means. What do they do to the vectors such that only real components stay? What does it tell us about the transform?

> The following corollary is false for real inner-product spaces, as
> shown by considering any operator on a real inner-product space that
> is not self-adjoint.
>
> 7.3 Corollary: Let V be a complex inner-product space and let T ∈ L(V ). Then T is self-adjoint if and only if ⟨T v , v ⟩ ∈ R for every v ∈
> V.

My question is what does the fact that ⟨T v , v ⟩ always being real say about the orientation of Tv to v? How are they relative to each other in space such that the complex components cancel each other out?

As an example:
Suppose 2 dimensional complex vectors $⟨T[c,d] , [c,d] ⟩ = a \bar c + b \bar d$ = (2 + 4i) + (5-4i) = 7

What would 7 be representing here? Each component did have complex part but they cancelled each other out.

The proof is for reference but it is unimportant for the question

> Proof: Let v ∈ V. Then ⟨T v , v ⟩ − ⟨T v , v ⟩
>
> = ⟨T v , v ⟩ − ⟨v , T v
> ⟩
>
> = ⟨T v , v ⟩ − ⟨T ∗ v , v ⟩
> =⟨ (T −T∗)v,v ⟩.
>
> If ⟨Tv,v⟩ ∈ R for every v ∈ V, then the left side of the equation above equals 0, so ⟨(T − T∗)v,v⟩ = 0 for every v ∈ V.
> This implies that T − T ∗ = 0 (by 7.2), and hence T is self-adjoint.